# How to access a .ascx page from another View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view: User.  In that I have an ascx page : Details
I have a view : Test.  I want to access the Details from User from test, using render partial.  How can I do that?

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("Details"); %> doesn`t work in this case.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use /views/User/Details or put it in the shared folder.

**EDIT**

Insert this into Global.asax and call in Application_Start

```
    public static void RegisterViewEngine()
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();

        WebFormViewEngine viewEngine = new WebFormViewEngine();

        viewEngine.PartialViewLocationFormats = (new[] {
            "~/Views/Shared/PartialViews/{0}.ascx",
            "~/Views/{1}/PartialViews/{0}.ascx"
          }).Concat(viewEngine.PartialViewLocationFormats).ToArray();

        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(viewEngine);
    }
```

Then you can create a PartialViews folder in all your Views folders and you can reference partial view without needing to use paths.

So;

- Home
- Home : PartialViews
- Shared
- Shared : PartialViews

Obviously you need to put your partial view into the PartialViews folder for it to be visible.  :)

But if you look at the c# code you should be able to work out what it's doing and come up with your own paths etc.